# What are margins in Storyboard, and why does the iPhone 6 plus have different side margins than the other iPhones?

Tags: iphone, storyboard, xcode6, iphone-6-plus

When creating constraints in my views in Xcode 6, I noticed this "*constrained to margin*" box which is ticked by default:

[image]

The result of keeping this box ticked is that I the app would run normally on all iPhones except iPhone 6 Plus where I would have some margins on the left and right of the view:

[image: iPhone 6]
[image: iPhone 6+]

I tried looking at Apple's documentation, but maybe not hard enough. What is margin in Xcode 6 and above? Why is the margin only on the sides and not on the top/bottom? And why is it that only iPhone 6 Plus has this margin? Why not iPhone 6 and others? Are those margins documented somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

You need to click "relative to margin" in the horizontal space constraint attributes

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. What I'm wondering is why the margin is only on iPhone 6+ but not iPhone 6.